# Cannot add .expo folder to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to add `.expo` folder of my react-native (expo) project to the `.gitignore` file. Unfortunately, `git` still tracking all files within `.expo` folder.

`.gitignore` file looks like this

```
# Expo
.expo
.expo/web
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Take a look at the comments below. They helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/11005213

Comment: Have these files ever been tracked in the repo? If yes, adding them to `.gitignore` now won't be enough.

Comment: If the files were already tracked, you'll have to first remove them (`git rm --cached FILENAME`) to then ignore.

Comment: Thank you, guys. The `git rm -r --cached <folder>` command worked for me.